# Trying to move my object initialisation and method calls out of my Main method

Tags: methods, coding-style, program-entry-point, convention

I am trying to move some code out of the main method and use it in another class. The reason for doing this is that I learnt it was advised convention to do so and I am relatively new to Java so looking to try it out. Currently when I move the code into the 'Game' class I cannot resolve the errors that eclipse is showing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Main method in playGame class-

```
 public class playGame {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            player playerOne = new player();
            GameHelper gameHelper = new GameHelper(); 
            wordManipulator thisWord = new wordManipulator();
            gameHelper.showDisplay();
            playerOne.setPlayerName();
            gameHelper.showIntro(playerOne.getPlayerName());
            thisWord.showHiddenWord();
            playerOne.setPlayerGuess();

        }

    }
```

The Game class

```
public class Game {

//other code for the game logic

}
```

Comment: Hey, I thought I'd add some more details in case it helps anyone provide answers, these are the errors I see when I move the code into the Game class:
"Syntax error on token "showDisplay", Identifier expected after this token"
and
"Syntax error on token "boolean", @ expected"

Comment: Thanks to anyone who looked into this.
I worked it out in the end.
I was stupidly trying to put the code straight into the 'Game' class, it should have been part of a method i.e. startGame of the 'Game class. All sorted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to put your code in a method in the Game class, and then call that specific method.

Another hint : use capitals for class names.

Comment: Thanks, I realise this was from years ago, but I didn't comment at the time- apologies this was helpful.